# Deploying Web App under IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7

I am trying to deploy application under existing application on IIS , I want the child application to look at a different path from the parent app.. I already changed its physical path , however when I try to browse it ,it goes to the physical path of the parent .
I am not very experienced in IIS , so does anybody know why I get that ?

[image: the configured physical path]
[image: request result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to understand, and I'm not seeing enough information here to provide a definitive answer. However, it seems that you're confusing virtual paths with physical paths. IIS (and other web servers) do not expose the path on the filesystem, instead they create a virtual path that maps to some filesystem location. As an example, let's say you had the following applications residing at the following directories:

- Foo (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\foo)
- Bar (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bar)

And "Bar" is an application under "Foo" in the IIS site tree. Then, if you wanted to request some static resource under the "Bar" app, the URL would be something like:

```
http://domain.com/bar/image.jpg
```

While a request for `http://domain.com/image.jpg` would hit the "Foo" application. Here, though, even the "bar" part of the URL is virtual. It's based on the virtual path you set for the sub-application. The actual phsyical directory could be named entirely differently.

Long and short, anything you're trying to call in a sub-application will need to be prefixed with the virtual path of that sub-application and has zero bearing on where the application is physically located on the server.

Comment: I mean I have a deployed application that looks at a physical path "C:\MyWebsite" and i want  to deploy another application under the deployed one . When I give the application a different physical path say ""C:\MyNewWebsite"  and try to open a page it says not found because it goes to "MyWebsite"